# Heap corruption occurs when clearing my linked list

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

The code below works properly. It can clear the list.

```
typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* node;
}node;

typedef struct List {
    node* head;
    int length;
}list;

int main() {
    list* L = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
    L->head = NULL;
    L->length = 0;
    node* p;

    node* head = NULL;
    head = malloc(sizeof(node));

    head->data = 1;
    head->node = NULL;

    L->head = head;

    while (L->head != NULL) {
        p = L->head;
        L->head = L->head->node;
        free(p);        
    }
}
```

But the code below occurs error in the 'free(p)' function.

```
void insert(list* L, int x) {
    node* newnode = (node*)malloc(sizeof(newnode));
    newnode->data = x;

    if (L->head == NULL) {
        newnode->node = NULL;
        L->head = newnode;
    }
    else {
        newnode->node = L->head;
        L->head = newnode;
    }
}

int main() {
    list* L = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
    L->head = NULL;
    L->length = 0;
    node* p;

    insert(L, 10);

    while (L->head != NULL) {
        p = L->head;
        L->head = L->head->node;
        free(p);        
    }
}
```

I looked for information about HEAP CORRUPTION error and found that it happens when try to free memory over the range. But, only difference between two codes is using function or not on the insertion. So, why such thing like this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is incorrect:

```
node* newnode = (node*)malloc(sizeof(newnode));
```

Note that `sizeof(newnode)` is the size in bytes of a *pointer*, because that's what `newnode` is.  Because `struct node` is necessarily larger than a pointer, you have undefined behavior when you initialize its members.  Essentially, you are writing to memory that you do not own.

You actually want `sizeof(node)` or `sizeof(*newnode)` because you're trying to allocate a node structure:

```
node* newnode = malloc(sizeof(node));
```

Note above I have removed the cast, since casting the return value of `malloc` is an anti-pattern in C.  The only reason to cast is if you're using a C++ compiler, but if so then you should have marked your question as C++ and be using `new` instead of `malloc` anyway.